# Merge two stdClass object array in php

Tags: php, stdclass

I have the following two stdClass array from a loop. Now I need to merge them when when the key 'id' matches.

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[28]
      public 'id' => string '78' (length=2)
      public 'quantity' => string '5' (length=1)




array (size=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'product_id' => string '78' (length=2)
      public 'quantity' => string '1' (length=1)
```

So the final array become

```
array (size=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'product_id' => string '78' (length=2)
      public 'quantity' => string '6' (length=1)
```

Any help on how to do that ? I decode the original data using json_decode from `[{"id":"78","quantity":"1"}]` this format of data.

Comment: Is array1 and array2 a database resultset? Have you tried to loop the first array and map the second array?

Comment: Yes, They are database resultset. they are basically serialized string in database which when pulled are json_decode. They are from same loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an extra parameter to the `json_decode`, you can get the data as an associative array, which is much easier to work with.  I've done a couple of versions ( the first is PHP 7 ), pick one which works with your system.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$arr1 = json_decode('[{"id":"78","quantity":"1"}, {"id":"79","quantity":"3"}]', true);
$arr2 = json_decode('[{"id":"78","quantity":"5"}]', true);

$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

// V7
$result = [];
foreach ( $arr3 as $element )   {
    $result[$element['id']] = ($result[$element['id']]??0)
              + $element['quantity'];
}

print_r($result);
// Prior to V7
$result = array();
foreach ( $arr3 as $element )   {
    if ( !isset($result[$element['id']]) ){
        $result[$element['id']] = 0;
    }
    $result[$element['id']] += $element['quantity'];
}

print_r($result);
```

I've added another element to show how this adds up, but the output of this is...

```
Array
(
    [78] => 6
    [79] => 3
)
Array
(
    [78] => 6
    [79] => 3
)
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that maintains the format in your original question.
It also uses array_reduce which is a concise way to process an array.

```
<?php
$input1 = '[{"id":"78","quantity":"7800"},
    {"id":"79","quantity":"7900"},
    {"id":"80","quantity":"8000"}]';
$input2 = '[{"id":"78","quantity":"6"},
    {"id":"79","quantity":"8"},
    {"id":"80","quantity":"6"},
    {"id":"81","quantity":"7"}]';

$input1Arr = json_decode($input1);
$input2Arr = json_decode($input2);

$combinedArrays = array_merge($input1Arr, $input2Arr);

echo "combinedArrays = " . print_r($combinedArrays, true) . "\n";

$result = array_reduce($combinedArrays, 
    function($intermediateResult, $item){
        if ( ! array_key_exists($item->id, $intermediateResult) ) {
            // First time encountering an object with this id
            $intermediateResult[$item->id] = $item;
        }
        else {
            // We have an object with this id already so just add the quantity
            $intermediateResult[$item->id]->quantity += $item->quantity;
        }
        return $intermediateResult;
    }, []);
// Get the values from the result array
print_r(array_values($result));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks !